# how to center img inide img slider from bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Im having problem centering the img to its place using bootstrap 5 img slider carousel:
[image]

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="../images/1.jpg" class="w-25" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="../images/2.jpg" class="w-25" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="../images/3.jpg" class="w-25" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

I took the code from: [bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#with-indicators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, You have set 25% with of carousal item image. So, You will need to add text align center for carousal item. You can use simple `text-center` bootstrap class for that.

Your `<div class="carousel-inner">` code should be as below:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item text-center active">
        <img src="../images/1.jpg" class="w-25" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center">
        <img src="../images/2.jpg" class="w-25" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center">
        <img src="../images/3.jpg" class="w-25" alt="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

select the div of each image with their class in your CSS and write `text-align:center;` this way it gets centered. (Simply use the code I sent)

```css
.carousel-item{
    text-align: center;
}
```